# slow when using Select SQL Command in Big MDB File

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, ado

I'm using access 2000 mdb file with 500 MB size, when I make `Select * From MyTable Where Phone=7744111` it takes too long, over 30 second to get results.

How can I increase searching performance? (I'm using vb6 and ado 2.8)

Comment: Did you put an index on `Phone` column?

Comment: There three columns Phone and FirstName And LastName Only, how put index?

Comment: CREATE INDEX my_index ON MyTable.Phone;

Comment: Normally you should put an index on fields you use with `WHERE` clause... but this is not always true...

Comment: anyway your DB is quite small ;) - we handle cca. 15GB of data splitted upon several MDB files ;) - and really we haven't found any database faster than access in the way we use it - e.g. accessing records randomly by their ID

Comment: Can I plug the Microsoft book [Jet Database Engine Programmer's Guide](http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Database-Programmers-Professional-Editions/dp/1572313420)? Now only available secondhand, but usually very cheap for that reason. Chapter 13 *Optimizing Performance* is excellent. Rest of the book is very useful too..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

index the field [Phone] - seems you're doing full scan

also try giving exact column list instead of '*'

Comment: Thanks for Marco and Rezna after creating index now is real time results